# How do I direct traffic without redirecting in IIS7.5?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, rewrite

We have a production machine running Window Server 2003. Previously, development took place in a WAMP environment but a few users are moving to IIS.

The issue is, we have a directory on the server called /home/ that when visited, directs all information elsewhere.

For instance

```
yourwebsite.com/home/
```

would actually point to

```
yourwebsite.com/tabular/
```

without redirecting the page (i.e. the path wouldn't change)? How is this possible in IIS7.5?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: I answered your question below, but FYI - you should also start thinking about upgrading your OS because Microsoft has announced the end of support for Windows Server 2003 is July 14, 2015. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-server-2003/

Comment: Yes, no problem. That's one of the reasons a few users are on IIS 7.5 - it means we can test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install the [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for IIS.

Then you can write a rule that will rewrite yourwebsite.com/home/ to yourwebsite.com/tabular/

The rule will be stored in the web.config for the application. This example would rewrite all URLs under /home/ to /tabular/

```
<rule name="Rewrite home to tabular">
    <match url="^/home/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/tabular/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```